# Exportar métodos de uma dll em C++

Tags: c++, dll

Estou com um problema, minha dll não exportou os métodos para eu usar em outros programas.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
namespace integration {

    class RESTRequest {
        public:
            __declspec(dllexport) string GetPing(char* ping);
        private:
            static void MarshalString(String ^ s, string& os);
    };

}
```

Está compilando legal, porem quando eu tento acessar a ddl com um programa java, da esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetPing': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Pra mim a exportação se concretizava com `__declspec(dllexport)` no metodo, mas pelo jeito nao funcionou apenas com ele, tenho que adicionar mais algum deltalhe na dll ?

Comment: acho que um nome dentro de um namespace não consegue ser exportado para o Java...se for um método de uma classe, então deve ser um método "estático"...além disso, deve ser precedido de `extern "C"`...num caso simples (sem classes e sem namespaces) ficaria assim: `extern "C" declspec(dllexport) GetPing(char* ping);`

Comment: ops, no comentário coloquei "declspec", é "__declspec", claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilador Visual Studio 2005 (usado na linha de comando)

### DLL

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace N
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) C
    {
      public:
         void display();
         static C* createNewC() { return new C; }
   };
}

void N::C::display()
{
   cout << "*\n";
   cout << "* hello from N::C::display\n";
   cout << "*\n";
}
```

### TESTE

```
namespace N
{
   class __declspec(dllimport) C
   {
      public:
         void display();
         static C* createNewC();
   };
}

int main()
{
   N::C* c = N::C::createNewC();
   c->display();
}
```

### COMPILAÇÃO DA DLL

```
Wed  1 Feb 2017 04:52:00  >> { F:\projects\misc }                                  
$ cl /EHsc /LD testdll.cpp                                                         
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86   
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                         

testdll.cpp                                                                        
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 8.00.50727.762                            
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                         

/out:testdll.dll                                                                   
/dll                                                                               
/implib:testdll.lib                                                                
testdll.obj                                                                        
Creating library testdll.lib and object testdll.exp
```

### COMPILAÇÃO DO TESTE

```
$ cl /EHsc testdllmain.cpp testdll.lib                                                
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86      
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                            

testdllmain.cpp                                                                       
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 8.00.50727.762                               
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                            

/out:testdllmain.exe                                                                  
testdllmain.obj                                                                       
testdll.lib
```

### EXECUÇÃO DO TESTE

```
Wed  1 Feb 2017 04:45:04  >> { F:\projects\misc }                                     
$ testdllmain.exe                                                                     
*                                                                                     
* hello from N::C::display                                                            
*
```

Comment: ainda faltou exportar funções utilizáveis pelo Java, mas agora fica mais fácil